# Using the fillna() method from Pandas to replace a particular string value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-structures

I have a particular column(the column is called 'numbers') which outputs unique values like this:

```
df.numbers.unique()
```

Output:

```
([nan, '50', '22', '11', '46', '58', '22', '14', '18', '15', '33', 'XX'], dtype=object)
```

As seen above there are unidentified characters such as 'XX'. I wish to convert them to 'NaN' values instead.  I tried replacing these with using this code:

```
 df.numbers.replace('XX',np.NaN)
```

However, when I print the unique values in the column again. The 'XX' is still there. I wish to get rid of the 'XX' and replace them with 'NaN' instead. 
I am just curious to know why it is not working. 
Assistance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define "unidentified" characters? Both '33' and 'XX' are two-character strings.

Comment: Hmm it seems I will need to convert the dtype of the column first and the convert it. Let me alter the question @DyZ

Comment: Or could you help me give it a go by helping me to answer it? @DyZ

Comment: If you want to replace a _specific_ value, use `df.numbers[df.numbers=='XX']=np.nan`.

Comment: Ahh yes. So replace the 'XX' first and then convert the column?

Comment: @DyZ How can I change the data type from object to float or int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just forget to assign it back

```
df.numbers=df.numbers.replace('XX',np.NaN)
```

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks ! I want to convert the column to another data type how can I do that? Will this affect it?

Comment: @DeepakM df.number = pd.to_numeric(df.number)